# Device Force Close

Tags: java, android

I finally got a version of my game ready for publish, but when I tried running it on my HTC Hero, it force closes after a certain level and the logcat started showing than disappeared. On the emulator it works fine no issues at all but on the phone, if I use the menu button to restart the game it force closes or if I try to start a new game from one of the other activities it force closes, and as mentioned above it force closes after level 5 to 7.

When changing from activity to game:

```
07-11 20:40:27.314: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.hitmanassault/com.android.hitmanassault.Hitman}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.android.hitmanassault.HitmanView
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:126)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1932)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.android.hitmanassault.HitmanView
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1629)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at com.android.hitmanassault.Hitman.onCreate(Hitman.java:49)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     ... 11 more
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at com.android.hitmanassault.HitmanView.<init>(HitmanView.java:51)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     ... 21 more
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:464)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:340)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:363)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:389)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at com.android.hitmanassault.HitmanView$HitmanThread.<init>(HitmanView.java:180)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     at com.android.hitmanassault.HitmanView.ViewInit(HitmanView.java:65)
07-11 20:40:27.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15898):     ... 25 more
```

After level 5 - 7:

```
07-11 20:39:35.054: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15629): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-11 20:39:35.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15629): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
07-11 20:39:35.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15629):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
07-11 20:39:35.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15629):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:464)
07-11 20:39:35.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15629):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:340)
07-11 20:39:35.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15629):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:363)
07-11 20:39:35.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15629):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:389)
07-11 20:39:35.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15629):     at com.android.hitmanassault.HitmanView.createSprite(HitmanView.java:74)
07-11 20:39:35.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15629):     at com.android.hitmanassault.HitmanView.access$3(HitmanView.java:73)
07-11 20:39:35.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15629):     at com.android.hitmanassault.HitmanView$HitmanThread.initLevel(HitmanView.java:191)
07-11 20:39:35.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15629):     at com.android.hitmanassault.HitmanView$HitmanThread$1.run(HitmanView.java:284)
07-11 20:39:35.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15629):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:609)
07-11 20:39:35.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15629):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-11 20:39:35.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15629):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-11 20:39:35.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
07-11 20:39:35.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15629):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 20:39:35.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15629):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-11 20:39:35.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15629):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-11 20:39:35.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15629):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-11 20:39:35.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15629):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: There's no way to post your LogCat?

Comment: Not unless I can figure out how to make it re-appear :'(

Comment: I can't parse this: "... and the logcat started showing than disappeared." Is there a stack trace in your logcat?

Comment: Without the logcat its pretty hard to do anything.

Comment: I just realized that you probably meant "the logcat started showing and then disappeared". How were you displaying the logcat? Have you tried other methods like plugging into a computer and using `adb logcat` or Eclipse, or one of the many logcat tools on the Android Market like aLogcat or SendLog?

Comment: I have been displaying it through the android logcat for eclipse ADT

Comment: Use the command line: `adb logcat` will work even when Eclipse doesn't. Get that log and post it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are running out of memory. I would suggest you check out the link below for ways to avoid memory leaks.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

One thing to keep when using bitmaps is that you should use the `Bitmap.recycle()` method to clean up the bitmap memory if you are no longer going to use it.

Another thing to check out is make sure your assets are compressed. I have noticed when using an XML layout and loading a large uncompressed resource, you can get memory leaks.

If you use `ImageView`s and keep them around for any reason, make sure to keep a `WeakReference` to the `ImageView` rather than the `ImageView` itself so you will know if the ImageView has been cleaned up.

Comment: No, I use a linear layout and use the android:backgroud="@drawable/background" to set the background. For the Bitmap.recycle, I am not sure which bitmap to use it on. My background image is only 20kb and I used the bitmapfactory options class on it already.